# How to append the checked checkbox data to the top of the list in html <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I tried that in the table format its working but in `<div>` its not working. Is there any possibilities to append the checked check box data to the top of the list using `<div>` tag.

Comment: We need far more context. Any code samples, things you've tried?

Comment: if you know about append then you must be aware of prepend also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It may helps you.

**HTML Code**

```
 <ol type="1" id="List">
  <div class="ollist">
    <div class="group-title"><span>group one title</span></div>
    <div class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check-1" value="1" class="checkbox-custom" name="item_name[]" />
        <label for="Check-1" class="checkbox-custom-label">List 1</label>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check-2" value="2" class="checkbox-custom" name="item_name[]" />
        <label for="Check-2" class="checkbox-custom-label">List 2</label>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check-3" value="3" class="checkbox-custom" name="item_name[]" />
        <label for="Check-3" class="checkbox-custom-label">List 3</label>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check-4" value="4" class="checkbox-custom" name="item_name[]" />
        <label for="Check-4" class="checkbox-custom-label">List 4</label>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check-5" value="5" class="checkbox-custom" name="item_name[]" />
        <label for="Check-5" class="checkbox-custom-label">List 5</label>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ol>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.ollistollist .group-title').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.group-title', '.items').data('group', this);
  });

  $('.ollist .items').has('input:checked').prependTo('.ollistollist');

  $('.ollist').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var $item = $(this).closest('.items');
    if (this.checked) {
      $item.insertBefore($('.ollist .group-title').first())
    } else {
      $item.appendTo($item.data('group'))
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this as sample [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/ga5qgevb/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/ga5qgevb/)

```
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="Test1" />
<label for="cb1">Test1</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="Test2" />
<label for="cb2">Test2</label>
</p>

<div id="divList">
</div>

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
   var html="<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>";
    $("#divList").prepend(html);
   }
});
```